# Coreos on hyper-v, failed to start switch root

Tags: hyper-v, coreos

I tries to start coreos on hyper-v but it fails to load from ISO with `Failed to start switch root` error

I use `.vhd` disk and `generation 1` virtual machine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was my greediness, coreos need to have at least 1024 mb of RAM, otherwise it fails to load from ISO

Comment: Same thing for me on VMware Fusion.  It created the VM with 384MB by default.  When I bumped it up to 1024MB then CoreOS booted fine.